# R can't connect to Druid cluster only on rstudio-server

Tags: linux, java, database, r, jdbc

I'm running these lines to get R connected to a Apache Druid cluster:

```
> library("RJDBC")
> conn_string = "jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://<broker_url>:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica-protobuf/;serialization=protobuf"
> drv <- JDBC("org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver", "~/Downloads/avatica-1.23.0.jar")
> conn <- dbConnect(drv, conn_string)
```

It's working perfectly on RStudio desktop running on my machine, but it gets stuck at the third line (`drv <- JDBC(...)`) on RStudio Server running on one of my virtual machines.

I've alreary run `sudo R CMD javareconf JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`on that machine. I got the following answer:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_382
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-4A2Reg/r-base-4.1.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR

JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

What's wrong with my RStudio Server installation?

Comment: Note: I'm running Arch Linux on my machine, and Ubuntu 22.04 on my virtual machine (KVM).

Comment: Note 2: In debug mode, logs show the following, repeatedly: [rserver] DEBUG -- sent server proxy response for: /events/get_events (hadoop:89) in 10.0s id:: 200 <\n> [rserver] DEBUG - Start server proxy request POST /events/get_events (hadoop:90) for local stream: /var/run/rstudio-server/rstudio-rsession/hadoop-d

Comment: Note 3: Curiously, it works when executed from R from command-line flawlessly. Actually, this problem seen related to rJava, not only RJDBC.